# How to define a nested template

Tags: c++, templates, nested

I defined a function as below, which took an integer as a template parameter, it worked as expected.

```
template<int D, typename std::enable_if<std::greater<int>{}(D, 100), void*>::type = nullptr>
void func(int p) {
    // something
}
func<100>(1); // ERROR
func<101>(1); // OK
```

Now, I want to make the `int` as a template parameter too. Meaning that I need something like this:

```
template<T D, typename std::enable_if<std::greater<T>{}(D, 100), void*>::type = nullptr>
void func(int p) {
    // something
}
```

Well, I've tried as below but it's not compilable.

```
template<typename T, template<T D, typename std::enable_if<std::greater<T>{}(D, 100), void*>::type = nullptr>>
void func2(int p) {
    // something
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare `T` as type template parameter firstly. E.g.

```
template<typename T, T D, typename std::enable_if<std::greater<T>{}(D, 100), void*>::type = nullptr>
void func(int p) {
    // something
}
```

then

```
func<int, 100>(1); // ERROR
func<int, 101>(1); // OK
```

If you don't want to specify `int` explicitly, you can

```
template<auto D, typename std::enable_if<std::greater<>{}(D, 100), void*>::type = nullptr>
void func(int p) {
    // something
}
```

then

```
func<100>(1); // ERROR
func<101>(1); // OK
```

Comment: You see, I don't want to call it as `func<int, 101>`, I still want to do it as `func<101>(1)`. Is it possible?

Comment: @Yves Answer revised.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to C++17, use `auto` non-type template parameter:

```
template<auto D, typename std::enable_if<std::greater<>{}(D, 100), void*>::type = nullptr>
void func(int p) {
    // something
}
```

Comment: Alright, it seems that I have no choice because I have to work with c++11...